# RAGAS Evaluator for llm RAG application threw error

Tags: python, chatbot, huggingface, large-language-model, py-langchain

```
    from ragas.testset import TestsetGenerator
    from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
    from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
    from ragas.llms import LangchainLLM
    from ragas.llms import LangchainLLM

    llm_wrapper = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo")

    generator_llm = LangchainLLM(llm=llm_wrapper)
    critic_llm = LangchainLLM(llm=llm_wrapper)
    embeddings_model =  OpenAIEmbeddings() 

    testset_distribution = {
    "simple": 0.25,
    "reasoning": 0.5,
    "multi_context": 0.0,
    "conditional": 0.25,
       }

    chat_qa = 0.2


    test_generator = TestsetGenerator(
    generator_llm=generator_llm,
    critic_llm=critic_llm,
    embeddings_model=embeddings_model,
    testset_distribution=testset_distribution,
    chat_qa=chat_qa,
     )
    from ragas.llms import LangchainLLM

    from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
    data_file = "/content/"
    loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader(data_file+"/")
    documents = loader.load()
    testset = test_generator.generate(documents, test_size=2)
```

I could create the test data set using RAGAS llm evaluator. but I am not able to use evaluator function since it threw an error .  can anyone help me with it?

```
     from ragas import evaluate
     result = evaluate(
     testset, # selecting only 3
     metrics=[
        context_precision,
        faithfulness,
        answer_relevancy,
        context_recall,
      ],)
```

this threw error

```
AttributeError

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-214-4a046bb39140> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from ragas import evaluate
----> 2 result = evaluate(
      3     testset, # selecting only 3
      4     metrics=[
      5         context_precision,

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ragas/validation.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     10     Remap the column names in case dataset uses different column names
     11     """
---> 12     column_map = {k: v for k, v in column_map.items() if v in dataset.column_names}
     13     inverse_column_map = {v: k for k, v in column_map.items()}
     14     return dataset.from_dict(

AttributeError: 'TestDataset' object has no attribute 'column_names'
```

Comment: Which version of ragas do you have?

Comment: the ragas version is 0.0.21

Comment: Your traceback's ```validation.py``` looks different from the ```main``` branch of the repo.  I think your issue *might* be fixed by the next version.   I think try filing an issue with the ragas project.

Comment: Hi, Have you sorted out this error?

Comment: I suggest you try it one metric at a time instead of all 4 metrics at once. I'm facing problem with the context_recall but rest of the three metrics are working fine.